# Importing geometry field without clicking run in google earth engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

Hi I create a google earth engine code. I want to run this code without clicking run. So I create a button(test) that runs my all function. Also I get my date inputs with Textbox. However; the issue is when I select the geometry field and click my button that runs my functions, the code says; "select geometry". To solve this I must click to run button in code section after the geometry selection, however; In app version there is no run button. Is there an any method for importing geometry without clicking run[image]?

Comment: Please provide a minimal working script.

Comment: See: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/community/drawing-tools